# Is it possible to debug visual studio to view SqlConnection transactions

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sqlconnection, sqltransaction

I'm currently getting an error message in my asp.net application as an SQLCommand transaction is being committed, and I can't see how it is happening. The error message states:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SectorID', table 'EventHistory'; column does not allow nulls.
```

The error itself makes absolute sense - I shouldn't be able to add a row with a null SectorID into that table.  My problem is that I can't find anywhere in that section of code that it even tries to insert into that table.

So my question - is it possible to debug this in visual studio to allow me to see all transactions that are away to be committed? I think seeing the offending row might help me pinpoint where this row is being added.  I added an item in the watch window for `cmd.Transaction` as that looked as likely as anything but I couldn't find anything in the list of options so I'm not even sure if it's something that can be viewed when debugging.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a trace using the tool SQL Server Profiler. That should tell you exactly what query is being ran against the database which is raising that exception.

Comment: Ah that's a great idea.  Never used profiler before - it was exactly what I  needed to see all the queries.  Unfortunately it shows none of the entries as having a null ID so back to the drawing board for this particular issue but you certainly answered this question!  Thanks very much

Comment: Np glad I could help.